# Connect to another WP install and grab post based on custom field

Tags: database

This is the set up:
Two separate wordpress installs on two separate domains (not multi-site)

This is what I want to do
Query the posts from database one based on custom field and display them on the other Wordpress install

This is what I have done:
Created a metabox in the WP 1 install for custom field
Created a template in WP 2 install with the following query

$hbldb = new wpdb('username','password','dbasename','localhost');

$results = $hbldb->get_results(
  query_posts('meta_key=dbt_ffhpost&meta_value=on')
);

LOOP

The result:
404 - what you are looking for isn't here.

I know the issue is in the query - just don't know what.  Do I need to query the specific table, row, field etc?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you test the values `$hbldb` and `$results` before attempting to use them? You don't actually show us your code, so it's anyone's guess about what caused a 404. If nothing else, stick in a `print_r($hbldb)` and a `print_r($results)` in there and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I am obviously not a php programmer;-)  I put that in and it is connecting to the database - this is the result http://plantpurefoods.com/bluebird/blog-articles-page/

Comment: Looks like I need to query the specific table(s) to get the post I am looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The `query_posts()` inside your database call is being evaluated first, on the current site, and returning an array - which is probably empty, since its not the database you were expecting to be querying. Then that array of posts is being passed to the outer `$hbldb->get_results()` call, which is giving you your error, because it isn't a valid MySQL query syntax.

If you want to deal with the raw SQL query on your external database, you would have to write that entire query within your call to `get_results()`... ie, something like this:

```
$results = $hbldb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM 
                                {$hbldb->posts} posts 
                                JOIN {$hbldb->postmeta} meta
                                ON meta.post_id = posts.ID
                                WHERE meta.meta_key ='dbt_ffhpost'
                                AND meta.meta_value = 'on'",
                                ARRAY_A );
```

*(edited: added ARRAY_A argument to make this query return an array.)*

I think there must be a better way of doing this, but I can't quite wrap my head around how to to create a new WP_Query object that relates to a secondary wpdb object, or even if that's possible, so the best help I can give is the raw SQL.

And, once you have these results, you can loop through them like this:

```
<?php 

if ($results) : 

foreach ($results as $post) :

echo '<h2>'.apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title ).'</h2>';
echo '<h4>'.apply_filters( 'the_author', $post->post_author ).'</h4>';
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );

endforeach; endif;

?>
```

Note that getting more advanced data from this second WP install is much harder using this method. I didn't even deal with getting the permalinks, etc. If you need to get more data out of the other WP install, you might be better off setting up an RSS feed from that site and displaying items from that RSS feed on the first site using a plugin or basic `fetch_feed()` code.

Comment: The above code with the following revisions is REALLY close - it returns the result but not in the loop?

Comment: $hbldb = new wpdb('plantpur_wrd13','7PCXqFiUr5','plantpur_wrd13','localhost');


$results = $hbldb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM 
                                {$hbldb->wp_posts} wp_posts 
                                JOIN {$hbldb->wp_postmeta} wp_postmeta
                                ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
                                WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key ='dbt_ffh_post'
                                AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'on'" );

 

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

Comment: http://plantpurefoods.com/bluebird/blog-articles-page/

Comment: and yes I am using revised loop $pageposts = $hbldb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);<?php if ($pageposts): ?>
 <?php global $post; ?>
 <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
 <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

Comment: Ah, looks like the query is returning an object. Add ARRAY_A to the `get_results` call to make it return an array instead. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Also, not sure if setup_postdata will work. If it doesn't, try accessing the post properties directly, i.e. `echo apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title);` rather than `the_title()`.

Comment: I know I am so close here - I put in the array and the following   <?php if ($pageposts): ?>
  <?php global $post; ?>
  <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
    <?php

  

    {
        echo apply_filters('the_title', $wp_posts->post_title);
    }

?> and i am still getting not found.  Surely you can see my php skills;-)

Comment: Leave out the `global $post` and refer to `$post` with your foreach loop, not `$wp_posts`. I'll add an example loop to my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much goldenapples for your help.  I will 'pay it forward' for sure;-)  Incidentally I agree...  I think rss may be the way to go.

Comment: Agreed... When I realized what you were trying to do, RSS did seem much simpler. Would you go back and delete your earlier comments in this thread where you posted your db password? That information shouldn't be out in public... I'll delete this comment once you see it.

Comment: @Ann: You can [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), which signifies to others that this problem is solved for you, and gives both you and the answerer a "reputation increase" allowing you to do more on the site.